# Freepbx outbound calls through an FXO device (Grandstream GXW4108)

Tags: linux, voip

Im trying to use GXW4018 fxo gateway with freepbx. Inbound calls work as expected but outbound calls doesnt. Outbound calls work but i cant seem to be able to force an extension to dial out with A PARTICULAR ANALOG LINE ONLY. What is happening is that extensions can dial out through the least available FXO port. Users dial out with through port 1 on the fxo. if port 1 is in use, then port 2 is used and so on. What do i need to configure  on the fxo and or the freepbx to ensure that an extension WILL ALWAYS dial out through a given port ALL THE TIME ??

Product Model:     GXW4108
System Info Hardware Revision:         2.2 Rev A
Part Number:       966-00002-22A
Software Version:
Program :      1.4.1.4
Loader :       1.1.3.4
Boot :     1.1.3.2

Asterisk Ver. 11.13.0
FreePBX 12.0.1rc36

[PDF on dropbox showing configuration on freepbx and grandstream fxo device.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ky8wmw71dxqnyem/Config.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score -1):

You need to prepend 99x from the PBX call routing. x means the port number of your choice. e.g. 9935555555 will make the GXW410x to dial out 5555555 through port #3

Good luck